# How to compress an HTTP response with zlib for HTTP?

Tags: c, zlib, content-encoding

I am writing a small server http which always send his generated html page(it discard the client request). This is for a part of a larger program

I want to use content-encoding for minimizing the Local bandwith usage...

I started by trying this example:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <zlib.h>
#define CHUNK 1048576

const char * restrict UrList[] = {"An", "example", "of", "random","ASCII string"};

void reponse(int newsockfd)
{
    char * buffer=calloc(sizeof(char),4700);
    srand(time(0));
    sscanf(buffer,"<!DOCTYPE html>\ // hopfully this is a test as I don't hard code like this in real programs...
<html>\
<head>\
    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\
    <title color=\"white\">%s</title>\
    <body align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" >\
        <button onclick=\"launchFullscreen(document.body);\">%s!</button>\
    </body>\
</html>\0",UrList[(rand()%3)]);
    size_t inputLen = strlen(buffer);
    uLong maxOutputLen = compressBound(inputLen);
    char * destbuffer=malloc(inputLen);
    compress2(destbuffer,&maxOutputLen,buffer,inputLen,Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);
    sprintf(buffer,"200 OK\n\
Server: Serveur personalisé ayant pour but d'empêcher les accès au nom de domaines interdits de manière efficace\n\
X-Powered-By: GCC 4.8.1\n\
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0\n\
ETag: \"1390786010\"\n\
Content-Language: fr\n\
Vary: Accept-Encoding\n\
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\
\n\
%s \0",destbuffer);
    write(newsockfd,buffer,inputLen);
    free((void *)buffer);
    free((void *)destbuffer);
}

void main()
{
    struct  sockaddr_in6 client_address, server_address;
    int clilen,server_handle=socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (server_handle < 0)
        perror("Unable to create socket.");
    server_address.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_address.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
    server_address.sin6_port = 0x5000; // port 80
    if ( bind(server_handle, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof( server_address )) < 0)
        perror("Unable to bind.");
    listen(server_handle,1310730);
    clilen=sizeof(client_address);
    while(1)
    {
        // variables locales
        pthread_t parallel;

        int newsockfd=accept(server_handle, (struct sockaddr *) &client_address, &clilen);
        pthread_create(&parallel,NULL,reponse,(void *)newsockfd);
    }
}
```

which don't work, because when I launch `telnet 192.168.0.20 80` nothing is printed.

According a step by step exectution in GDB, the buffer have the correct value when write() is called
The main idea is that I can't compress a file directly since I need do in-memory operations on the results in the real program.

Comment: One note `sizeof(buffer)` will not give you size of the array, just the size of the `char` pointer.

Comment: things [would be easier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php "Compress a string - PHP") if [PHP](http://www.php.net) were as fast as C :( .

Comment: Are you sure you need the performance characteristics of C for your website? Many very busy websites get by perfectly fine with PHP and perhaps a PHP accelerator.

Comment: @GWW : Yes, as this is for a part of an another applications wich is (in more) expected to run from an initramfs. Also I tried with `(Ulong)(sizeof(char)*700)` and I'm still getting a segmentation fault in zlib...

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of problems:

1. You're calling `sscanf()` to read data out of an empty buffer right at the start.  I think you meant to use `sprintf()` to write your test data into the buffer (but really, use [`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) to avoid overflowing your buffer).
2. You're using the same buffer for input to the `compress2()` function as you are for output.  The documentation is not clear on if this is supported, so I would assume that it's not for safety.
3. You're lying to zlib about how big your output buffer is.  You're telling it that your buffer is `compressBound(...)` bytes, when in fact it's only 4700 bytes.  Because it's impossible to compress every possible data stream, there are some sequences of bytes which get larger after compression, so it's possible for zlib to try to overflow your buffer if you lie to it, and then can cause a segfault.  If you at least tell it the truth about how big your buffer is, it will fail with an error in that cause instead of trying to read/write memory out of bounds.
4. The 2nd parameter to `compress2()` is a *pointer* to a variable which is both an input and output parameter.  On input, it contains the *maximum* size of the output buffer, and on output, it receives the *actual* size of the compressed data.  You're passing an integer value (not a pointer) and ignoring the compiler warning about a conversion between integer and pointer types.  **Listen to your compiler!**

Here's how to properly call the `compress2()` function using separate input and output buffers:

```
// Error checking elided for expository purposes
const char *inputBuf = "the data to compress...";
size_t inputLen = strlen(inputBuf);

// Compute the maximum size of the compressed output and allocate an output
// buffer for it -- note that this will be LARGER than the input size
uLong maxOutputLen = compressBound(inputLen);
char *outputBuf = malloc(maxOutputLen);

// Compress the data and receive the compressed data size
uLong compressedLen = maxOutputLen;
int result = compress2(outputBuf, &compressedLen, inputBuf, inputLen, Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);

// Use the compressed data
...

free(outputBuf);
```

Comment: You completely forgot that the compress2() function introduces zeros at the begining of the buffer. So when I call the write() with strlen(), a lot of data is discarded... :)

Comment: @user2284570: Yes, there's that too -- you need to pass `send()` the actual buffer length (the `compressedLen` value in my sample code), not use `strlen()`, since the compressed data can contain zero bytes which would be seen as C string terminators.

Comment: @GWW : Sorry, I had to update my post, because I have an another problem which look to come from pthreads... When I try without pthreads, the message is printed with telnet, but I get an error in the web-browser telling the message is corrupt.